# Is there any way to check how much disk space has left on a EBS volume from cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am writing a cloudwatch trigger that automatically clears some old directories on a EBS volume based on free disk space. If the free disk space is less than 10%, the event triggers and we run a cleanup. Is there any way to do it directly from cloudwatch? All I read is writing a time schedule that automatically runs every few hours and check disk space in code or using the df command. Would that be the only way?

Comment: **Side-question:** When the "event" is triggered, how does it clear the disk space? Does somebody manually go into the instance, or does something from _outside_ the instance somehow access the instance itself? I ask because it could just be easier to run a `cron` job on the instance that checks its disk space and does the cleanup, rather than triggering something _external_ to the instance that then has to access the instance somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method is to [Collect Metrics and Logs from Amazon EC2 Instances and On-Premises Servers with the CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html).

- Install the CloudWatch Agent
- Create a configuration file to tell it which statistics to send to Amazon CloudWatch
- Assign an IAM Role to the instance with permissions to send the metrics

You could then create CloudWatch Alarms based upon the metrics.